# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “end-of-file” when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00103

[image]

and getting error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when 
expecting one of the following: 
;

Comment: where is your `id` defined? shouldn't it be `sid` in where clause?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 4):

few suggestions:

1. Check your where clause if you are correctly using the `id` field.
2. I think `endif` should be `end if` with space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Line number 22. Try `end if`, no`endif`

Answer (score 0):

Try defining spring.datasource.separator=^ in ur configuration file.